# Calculate the path integral: $\int_{\lambda}\left[2z+\sinh\left(z\right)\right]\,\mathrm{d}z$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Calculate the path integral:
$$\int_{\lambda}\left[2z + \sinh\left(z\right)\right]\,\mathrm{d}z$$

where $\displaystyle\lambda\left(t\right) =
\frac{t^{2}}{4} + \frac{\mathrm{i}t}{2}\,,\quad
\left(~0 ≤ t ≤ 4~\right)$.

Im not sure how to parameterize this and also how to answer the rest of the question so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can't you just find the anti-derivative ?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus for contour integrals:

> If $f$ is continuous on a domain $D$, then the integral along any path from $z_1$ to $z_2$ is given by
>   $$ \int_{z_1}^{z_2} f(z) \, dz = F(z_2) - F(z_1) $$
>   where $F$ is any antiderivative of $f$.